# Calcite Optimize cause duplicated column name error

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, apache-calcite

We use calcite to execute a mysql query, the SQL is:

```
select a.title, c.score from phx_ep.phx_gql_product a left join phx_ep.phx_gql_product_tag c on a.product_id = c.product_id limit 3
```

It's simple and clear, but calcite optimized it to:

```
SELECT `t2`.`title`, `t2`.`score`
FROM (SELECT *
FROM (SELECT `product_id`, `title`
FROM (SELECT *
FROM `phx_ep`.`phx_gql_product`
LIMIT 3) AS `t`) AS `t0`
LEFT JOIN (SELECT `product_id`, `score`
FROM `phx_ep`.`phx_gql_product_tag`) AS `t1` ON `t0`.`product_id` = `t1`.`product_id`
LIMIT 3) AS `t2`
```

Which caused a `Duplicate column name error`

If remove `'limit 3'`, it works well.

**Is it a bug?**

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing all the steps you took to optimize the query.  Your best bet would be to open an issue on [Calcite's issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CALCITE/issues) with a reproducible test case.